# Impact of object on liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, collision

When something drops into water, the dynamics related are complicated. I was wondering if there are some well-written papers/books about fluid dynamics that investigate in this specifically.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it's awesome. And it has links to fluid dynamics papers. [Two Vortex Rings Colliding in SLOW MOTION - Smarter Every Day 195](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVbdbVhzcM4)

Comment: There is a second channel that shows 12 hours of video that went into the multiyear effort to produce this. [Behind the Scenes: Two Vortex Rings Colliding in SLOWMO (4 yrs, 12 hour MEGACUT) Smarter Every Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm9l8-qngjM&t=39680s). 11:19:22 is an especially good shot that shows details of how the secondary vortices develop.